# Add key in Joi object if key does not exist

Tags: node.js, joi

I have a joi schema like this

```
Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string(),
  language: Joi.string(),
  birthday: Joi.date(),
  age: Joi.number().integer()
})
```

The input can contain `birthday` and `age` at the same time or just one of the keys. If one of the keys does not exist, I want the missing key to be automatically added with the string `"NULL"` like this

```js
//input
{
 "name": "Jane Doe",
 "language": "de",
 "birthday": "1960-06-27"
}
//modified to
{
 "name": "Jane Doe",
 "language": "de",
 "birthday": "1960-06-27",
 "age": "NULL"
}
```

Is there a way to automatically add a key with a default value, if the key is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`any.default([value])`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#anydefaultvalue):

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string(),
  language: Joi.string(),
  birthday: Joi.date(),
  age: Joi.number().integer().default(null)
});

console.log(schema.validate({
  "name": "Jane Doe",
  "language": "de",
  "birthday": "1960-06-27"
}));
```

Output:

```
{
  name: "Jane Doe",
  language: "de",
  birthday: Mon Jun 27 1960 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),
  age: null
}
```

I would prefer `null` rather then a string `"NULL"` because both `date` and `age` are not of type `string`.

Comment: I tried this and it's not working. I get an error saying age is required and if I turn it optional (`.optional()`), age is not added at all. I need the string `"NULL"` because my database is crashing otherwise

Comment: Seems to be more a problem related to your database query. Anyway: try `age: Joi.number().integer().default('NULL')` then.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your first suggestion actually works. The problem was some false declaration on my side. I used `const {error, value} = schema.validate(input);` for validation and then went further by using `input` again, whereas joi of course saved the changes in `value`